# RadioButton not deselecting

Tags: java, button, boolean

Here is my code, I want to unselect a radio button when I click on it again. Since I have some code that only works when none of the radiobuttons are selected.

```
    if (TablesOn == true) {
        TablesOn = false;
    } else {
        TablesOn = true;
    }

    if (jRadioButton1.isVisible()==true) {
      jRadioButton1.setVisible(false);
      jRadioButton2.setVisible(false);
      jRadioButton3.setVisible(false);
      jLabel3.setVisible(false);
      jLabel4.setVisible(false);
      jLabel5.setVisible(false);
    } else {
      jRadioButton1.setVisible(true);
      jRadioButton2.setVisible(true);
      jRadioButton3.setVisible(true);
      jLabel3.setVisible(true);
      jLabel4.setVisible(true);
      jLabel5.setVisible(true);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To deselect a `RadioButton` which is inside of `RadioGroup` and be able to then select it again, firstly get your `RadioGroup`:

```
RadioGroup rg = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.your_radio_group_name_in_layout);
```

And then do:

```
rg.check(-1);
```

Of course, you need some code to save last checked button number, and if it is pressed again, deselect it using the code above.